# Best Way to Visualize Large Number of Categories

Tags: d3.js, highcharts, data-visualization

I have a large number of categories with a quantitative value that I have to compare visually in a web app.  There's no way to group these categories together, they are independent of one another completely and have rather large value differences... Some counting in the hundreds others in the millions.

Visually, is there any good way to show this off?  I'm working in Highcharts and looking at D3 as well to render this data, however the big issue is coming from trying to fit all this data into an area in a webapp while maintaining visual clarity and context.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's a "large number"? 20, 200, 2000?

Comment: Have you any mockup? How big your data is?

Comment: @Maz Have you checked Donuts charts from highcharts?

Comment: @SebastianBochan The largest number is a few million, the smallest number is only a few hundred.  A lot gravitate toward the lower-end.  They're supposed to be representations of the data in our system, of which all the data should (must) have visibility, so charting that forces it into obscurity is 'bad' as the people pushing requirements indicate.

Comment: How you plan to visualisie milions values on the small area? Data should be grouped or something?

Answer (score 0):

How about using a tag cloud like approach? The bigger the category, the higher the value?

Answer (score 0):

See D3 and Highcharts are suitable for this kind of representation. What are your thoughts on the implementation...like how many figures you are looking. we have seen web-apps with more than 20 figures in a single page like FollowerWonk which uses more than 25 figures in single page.

However D3 is much vast in terms of the options that it provides. see this https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery. You can not see these with High-charts.

Answer (score 0):

A [treemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping) is probably best since it uses space efficiently and represents size reasonably well. Rectangle area is not as good as position or length for visual clarity, but it's better than circle area, word area, or angles.

[image]

In this example, color is random, but you can base it on another variable.

If your definition of "large" is under 100 or so then you might be able to use position or length with a dot plot or bar chart, respectively.

Comment: The differences is very large as specified by @Maz. Can nodes in tree map have children of different sizes at same level.

Comment: Yes, large value differences which means that there is usually a block dominating the entire treemap and you cannot see a good number of blocks due to this spacial domination.

Comment: Normally it's a good thing for a visualization to represent things fairly, so that if its value is 10000x bigger so is its representation. However, you can give some visual clarity and maintain intellectual clarity by first performing some transformation, such as a log transformation.

Comment: +1 I was thinking of this...but couldn't find any options for this. However Visual needs to be designed depending upon the target user's knowledge. Log based transformation won't be useful for basic users. Whats your thought @xan

Comment: @KhushalDave I don't like log for area or length visuals, because there is no natural 0. Even if you set some artificial floor, like 1 in this case, you're still throwing away most of the free visual processing our eyes do and asking the users to do more mental work. Nonetheless, with the parameters of the question, _something_ has to give: screen space, completeness, visual clarity, simplicity, ...

Comment: @xan thats true! And it somehow degrades the quality of information that is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a Tag-Cloud like approach. For your Data-Set it seems best to use a tag-cloud with a zoom like feature. I can't think of an existing solution for this but without any kind of zoom your small values might end up beeing unreadable (see @xan's answer). The huge values would zoom really huge (and bleed off the widget) to not disturb the view.