# In pandas, how to properly label a Bar Chart with massive number of records?

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, bar-chart

I have a pandas series with about 200 rows, containing a integer count in each.

I am trying to plot the series on a bar graph, using the following line of code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(40, 40)
country_wise_counts.plot(kind='bar', y='Number of Users', x='Country Name', subplots=False, legend = False, fontsize=12)
```

and I get a plot as follows:

[image]

which clearly is not helpful.

So my first question is:

1. Is it a sane attempt, trying to plot my data this way, when I have 200 separate values that I want to plot on a bar graph?
2. If yes, how do I do what I want to do?

Comment: Bar plots are inherently categorical. You have to label all the of categories, because there's no logical way for the audience to fill in the gaps between e.g., lion, giraffe, buffalo. So yes, plotting 200 categories on a single axis isn't really going to work.

Comment: what would be a good way to visualize the dataset then?

Comment: If it's absolutely necessary to plot all 200 values I would go with a horizontal bar chart. Well, even if using only plotting a few of them I would prefer a horizontal.

Comment: There are so many ways to answer that question that have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24253628/best-way-to-visualize-large-number-of-categories

Comment: @PaulH: In my defense, I was born yesterday(into data visualization related stuff)